# Does Canada have regulations regarding "shorting against the box"?

Tags: taxes, canada, capital-gains-tax, shorting-securities, law

If you hold a long position in a stock and believe it will go down but don't want to realize any gains, you can a open short position in that same stock to hedge against any drops in the price. This strategy of "shorting against the box" is [restricted in the United States](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sellagainstthebox.asp) due to the Taxpayer Relief Act of 1997. Are there any similar regulations in Canada or other countries?

Comment: what's the difference between that and selling the stock?

Comment: Did you find an answer ?  I have the same question, and actually worse I already did short against the box (stocks I owned already) but rather just kind of "evolved" into this strategy as I often sell options and do strategies which end up in me shorting the stock (selling calls on a margin then get exercised). So I really would like to find the answer, before I get into (more) trouble  ;-)

Comment: @deryb I have yet to find an answer :( But, I also haven't encountered any explicit suggestion that shorting against the box is disallowed. So needless to say, I have no idea what the answer is!

Comment: @wispi Me neither, I did search quite a lot and posted this question  [reddit too](https://www.reddit.com/r/CanadianInvestor/comments/xvz3kx/is_shorting_against_the_box_allowed_in_canada/) but no definite (official) answer. So, I decided to simply avoid this "gray area", it's too risky (tax wise, not to mention shorting which implies sufficient trading mastery). Rather better err on the safe side by hedging / playing downsides using options. I prefer selling (calls & puts) than buying, to pocket premiums and time decay.